# Moving MySQL export to a publicly accessible directory with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linux, permissions

Running Ubuntu Server 14.04

Created a PHP script that runs a MySQL query which exports a CSV into /var/lib/mysql. Anytime this PHP script is ran, it will export the CSV.

I'm exporting to /var/lib/mysql due to permissions. For whatever reason, I couldn't get MySQL to export to a publicly accessible directory within my webroot (e.g. /var/www/html/exports/) even after chown mysql:mysql and chmod 777.

Because of that, I decided to simply use some PHP file operations to try to move the export CSV from /var/lib/mysql to /var/www/html/exports with the following code:

```
rename("/var/lib/mysql/export.csv", "/var/www/html/exports/export.csv");
```

My server log keeps telling me "Permission denied" whenever that line of code is executed.

So my question: How do I move a file of different ownerships with PHP to another directory owned by www-data or root?

Additional Details: This PHP file is executed from a web browser if that matters - not executed from bash.

Permission on my exports folder: **drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K Nov 25 09:46 exports**

Comment: I doubt PHP has access to `/var/lib/mysql`. Allowing non-mysql user accounts read access to that tree could potentially leak the raw mysql data files, which would be a security breach. You'd have to dump to `/tmp`, then move the file away from there.

Comment: So on a default Linux setup, PHP and MySQL should have rights to export to /tmp?

Comment: /tmp should be wide open for anyone/anything to write to.

Comment: Nice! Trying it now...

Comment: Can export to /tmp no problem but unable to move the file to my exports directory from there using PHP. Permission still denied. Must be something about my exports directory: drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K Nov 25 09:46 exports